# How to fix Arduino optocoupler + LED that doesn't light up?

Tags: arduino, led, opto-isolator

I'm having a hard time understanding how an optocoupler works. I made a circuit based on example 15 if the Arduino projects book. Instead of trying to hack a button, I'm trying to just light an LED on either side of the optocoupler. I'm misunderstanding how this should work because the LED I'm trying to light doesn't light.

My [youtube video shows my circuit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL7gv9uQxRQ). You can see the blue LED which runs from pin 2 of the optocoupler into ground lights up, but the red LED (which works, I verified) which runs from pins 4 to pin 5 of the optocoupler does not. I was under the impression that if I emitted high from the arduino to the pin 1 of the optocoupler through a 220 resistor (mine is 270 actually) and provided a path to ground that the optocoupler would be switched on and I would get current and ground from the pins on the other side.

Any suggestions - what am I missing?

Comment: Please write the part number of the optocoupler. A circuit diagram would be good too.

Comment: Or a link to the "Example 15".

Usually there are 2 seperate power and grounds in use with an opto-isolator. It maybe looks like only one is connected? You can't really diagnose with out a schematic like @gunnish said.

here is a link to an arduino to an optocoupler example on youtube. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gxa5l3gD8bc

Comment: WHICH Arduino projects book?

Answer (score 3):

Re: Comments - the project book is titled the Arduino Project book. It comes with the Arduino Uno starter kit.

Re: Schematic - yea, I'm not quite at making those yet. Next time :(

Re: The answer -

I just figured it out, soooo...silly me. Optocouplers don't supply their own power. They're just a switch. So in the example video above there is nothing powering the 2nd LED.

The working model with both LEDs lit is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CF1xPcXGNY&feature=youtube_gdata_player&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D_CF1xPcXGNY%26feature%3Dyoutube_gdata_player&nomobile=1

This link was super helpful in case anyone else stumbles on it: http://www.technogumbo.com/projects/Learning-to-Use-an-Optocoupler-or-OptoIsolator/